# Group results by day and month (php timestamp) showing total revenue per day

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql how can I group together by day and month showing tghe total revenue?

E.g. (not based on below data)

```
day month revenue
1   01    10.97
2   01    3.57
3   01    0
```

etc.

Heres an example of my data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
  `id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `product` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `market` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `revenue` float NOT NULL,
  `Units` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Downloads` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=138 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sales`
--

INSERT INTO `sales` (`id`, `timestamp`, `revenue`) VALUES
(1, 1394150400, 3.65),
(2, 1394064000, 0),
(4, 1393977600, 0),
(5, 1393891200, 7.42),
(6, 1393804800, 0),
(7, 1393718400, 0),
(8, 1393632000, 0),
(9, 1393545600, 0),
(10, 1393459200, 0),
(11, 1393372800, 0),
(12, 1393286400, 3.65),
(13, 1393200000, 3.65),
(14, 1393177032, 0),
(15, 1393090632, 3.65),
(16, 1393004232, 0),
(17, 1392917832, 0),
(18, 1392831432, 0),
(19, 1392745032, 0),
(20, 1392658632, 0),
(21, 1392572232, 0),
(24, 1391881032, 0),
(23, 1392485832, 0),
(25, 1392336000, 0),
(26, 1392249600, 0),
(27, 1392163200, 0),
(28, 1392076800, 0),
(29, 1391990400, 3.81),
(30, 1391904000, 0),
(31, 1391817600, 0),
(32, 1391731200, 3.65),
(33, 1391644800, 3.58),
(34, 1391558400, 3.58),
(35, 1391472000, 0),
(36, 1391385600, 0),
(37, 1391299200, 0),
(38, 1391212800, 7.23),
(39, 1391126400, 0),
(40, 1391040000, 0),
(41, 1390953600, 3.81),
(42, 1390867200, 4.52),
(43, 1390780800, 0),
(44, 1390694400, 3.65),
(45, 1390608000, 3.81),
(46, 1390585032, 0),
(47, 1390435200, 0),
(48, 1390348800, 3.58),
(49, 1390262400, 0),
(50, 1390176000, 0),
(51, 1390089600, 0),
(52, 1390003200, 0),
(53, 1389916800, 3.58),
(54, 1389893832, 0),
(55, 1389744000, 0),
(56, 1389657600, 0),
(57, 1389571200, 0),
(58, 1389484800, 0),
(59, 1389398400, 3.65),
(60, 1389312000, 3.18),
(61, 1389225600, 0),
(62, 1389139200, 0),
(63, 1389052800, 0),
(64, 1389052800, 0),
(65, 1388966400, 3.65),
(66, 1388880000, 4.05),
(67, 1388793600, 0),
(68, 1388707200, 3.65),
(69, 1388620800, 0),
(70, 1388534400, 0),
(71, 1394236800, 0),
(72, 1394236800, 2.51),
(73, 1394236800, 0),
(74, 1394150400, 5.02),
(75, 1394150400, 2.76),
(76, 1394064000, 7.5),
(77, 1394064000, 8.28),
(78, 1393977600, 0),
(79, 1393977600, 0),
(80, 1393891200, 7.5),
(81, 1393891200, 2.36),
(82, 1393804800, 0),
(83, 1393804800, 0),
(84, 1393718400, 2.76),
(85, 1393718400, 0),
(86, 1393632000, 0),
(87, 1393545600, 0),
(88, 1393545600, 2.76),
(89, 1393459200, 2.51),
(90, 1393459200, 2.51),
(91, 1393433613, 2.51),
(92, 1393433613, 0),
(93, 1393286400, 2.54),
(94, 1393286400, 2.76),
(95, 1393200000, 2.52),
(96, 1393200000, 5.51),
(97, 1394323200, 0),
(98, 1394323200, 5.01),
(99, 1394323200, 5.52),
(100, 1394409600, 0),
(101, 1394409600, 2.05),
(102, 1394409600, 5.27),
(103, 1393113600, 5.08),
(104, 1393027200, 5.09),
(105, 1392854400, 5.32),
(106, 1392854400, 7.63),
(107, 1392940800, 0),
(108, 1392595200, 0),
(109, 1392508800, 7.64),
(110, 1392422400, 0),
(111, 1392336000, 2.58),
(112, 1392163200, 5.57),
(113, 1391990400, 0),
(114, 1391817600, 0),
(115, 1391731200, 15.99),
(116, 1391472000, 10.66),
(117, 1391385600, 2.54),
(118, 1391299200, 2.54),
(119, 1391212800, 5.34),
(120, 1391040000, 0),
(121, 1390953600, 2.55),
(122, 1390780800, 10.9),
(123, 1390608000, 12.72),
(124, 1390435200, 7.64),
(125, 1390262400, 2.55),
(126, 1390089600, 9.92),
(127, 1389916800, 2.55),
(128, 1389744000, 2.55),
(129, 1389571200, 5.1),
(130, 1389398400, 2.55),
(131, 1389225600, 5.1),
(132, 1389052800, 7.65),
(133, 1388880000, 5.1),
(134, 1388793600, 9.99),
(135, 1388620800, 0),
(136, 1394582400, 4.14),
(137, 1394582400, 2.76);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`),'%d') DAY, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`),'%m') MONTH, SUM(`revenue`)
FROM sales
GROUP BY DAY,MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH,DAY
```

[**Check the FROM_UNIXTIME Function Here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)